# problem in classes with same name and parent in DLL and EXE but with different implementation

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries

I have a class with name Menu and this class compiled with both dll and exe. i have another class with name ChildMenu that inherit from Menu  and this class compiled with both dll and exe too.

i have a function in dll that create ChildMenu and return it as Menu.

```
extern "C"
{
   Menu* createMenu();
}
```

and with implementation of

```
Menu* createMenu()
{
    return new ChildMenu();
}
```

when I change the behavior of ChildMenu class in dll and recompile it but not in the exe, the behavior of the class not changed until i change the behavior of the class in exe and recompile it too.

ChildMenu has override one of Menu methods.the behavior change happend in overridden method.

i created the ChildClass in dll but its behavior comes from exe class.

why this happend?

Comment: This looks more like a design issue to me. Perhaps your DLL shouldn't have anything to do with your `ChildMenu` class at all?

Comment: What IDE are you using? And how is your project set up?

Comment: @Kanjiu why? i use vscode and compile the code with gcc

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude even if it is design issue i want to know why this happend.

Comment: It happens because you have two different implementations of the class. While the executable and the DLL are built separately, it's still breaks [the One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule), and lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  I know but dll and exe have a different linkage right?

Comment: Yes, and the DLL doesn't know anything about the definition in the EXE, and the EXE doesn't know anything about the definition in the DLL. Why are you even surprised that two different implementations of a class behaves differently?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the class is created in dll then i expect that it behave like i implement in dll

Comment: That's not how it works. You should look at the DLL as a *completely separate program*. The code in the EXE and the DLL have *nothing* in common once built. All the EXE have is a pointer to what it *believes* is a `ChildMenu` object, an instance of *its **own*** `ChildMenu` class. Which is totally separate and different from any `ChildMenu` class in the DLL. The two  different `ChildMenu` classes might not even be related at all!

Comment: Assuming your goal is to separate interface and implementation, that's laudable and good. But you separate implementation from a *different* implementation. Either you move *all* of the `ChildMenu` class into the DLL, *or* move it all into the EXE. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: As a possible third solution, move the `ChildMenu` class (both interface *and* implementation) into a separate *second* DLL. And then both your EXE and main DLL can use the second DLL for the `ChildMenu`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for other solutions. i just surprised for behavior.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "change the behavior of ChildMenu"? What exactly did you do?

Comment: @aybassiouny i edited my question to answer your question there.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in gcc by default the symbols in shared libraries exported. I fix the problem by hiding the visibility of the classes;